# Plotting multiple time series on the same plot using ggplot()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am fairly new to R and am attempting to plot two time series lines simultaneously (using different colors, of course) making use of ggplot2.

I have 2 data frames. the first one has 'Percent change for X' and 'Date' columns.  The second one has 'Percent change for Y' and 'Date' columns as well, i.e., both have a 'Date' column with the same values whereas the 'Percent Change' columns have different values.

I would like to plot the 'Percent Change' columns against 'Date' (common to both) using ggplot2 on a single plot.

The examples that I found online made use of the same data frame with different variables to achieve this, I have not been able to find anything that makes use of 2 data frames to get to the plot. I do not want to bind the two data frames together, I want to keep them separate. Here is the code that I am using:

```
ggplot(jobsAFAM, aes(x=jobsAFAM$data_date, y=jobsAFAM$Percent.Change)) + geom_line() +
  xlab("") + ylab("")
```

But this code produces only one line and I would like to add another line on top of it.
Any help would be much appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`ggplot` allows you to have multiple layers, and that is what you should take advantage of here.

In the plot created below, you can see that there are two `geom_line` statements hitting each of your datasets and plotting them together on one plot. You can extend that logic if you wish to add any other dataset, plot, or even features of the chart such as the axis labels.

```
library(ggplot2)

jobsAFAM1 <- data.frame(
  data_date = runif(5,1,100),
  Percent.Change = runif(5,1,100)
)

jobsAFAM2 <- data.frame(
  data_date = runif(5,1,100),
  Percent.Change = runif(5,1,100)
)

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = jobsAFAM1, aes(x = data_date, y = Percent.Change), color = "red") +
  geom_line(data = jobsAFAM2, aes(x = data_date, y = Percent.Change), color = "blue") +
  xlab('data_date') +
  ylab('percent.change')
```

Comment: Thanks@TheComeOnMan!! This works fantastic; is there a way I can merge the legends?

Comment: How can I add the legend, @TheComeOnMan?

Answer (score 51):

If both data frames have the same column names then you should add one data frame inside `ggplot()` call and also name x and y values inside `aes()` of `ggplot()` call. Then add first `geom_line()` for the first line and add second `geom_line()` call with `data=df2` (where df2 is your second data frame). If you need to have lines in different colors then add `color=` and name for eahc line inside `aes()` of each `geom_line()`.

```
df1<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))
df2<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))

ggplot(df1,aes(x,y))+geom_line(aes(color="First line"))+
  geom_line(data=df2,aes(color="Second line"))+
  labs(color="Legend text")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it achieved exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: @Didzis nice example, but what if I want to apply my customized colors (Eg. black and orange) and names? It looks that you are using color= as the "y" name.

Comment: @DarwinPC If you need to change colors and labels inside the legend then you can use `scale_color_manual()`

Comment: @DidzisElferts What if x and y values in df2 are different?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using the `ggfortify` library. It is a `ggplot2` wrapper that recognizes the type of object inside the autoplot function and chooses the best ggplot methods to plot. At least I don't have to remember the syntax of ggplot2.

```
library(ggfortify)
ts1 <- 1:100
ts2 <- 1:100*0.8
autoplot(ts( cbind(ts1, ts2)  , start = c(2010,5), frequency = 12 ),
         facets = FALSE)
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but it is still relevant. You can take advantage of reshape2::melt to change the dataframe into a more friendly structure for ggplot2.

Advantages:

- allows you plot any number of lines
- each line with a different color
- adds a legend for each line
- with only one call to ggplot/geom_line

Disadvantage:

- an extra package(reshape2) required
- melting is not so intuitive at first

For example:

```
jobsAFAM1 <- data.frame(
  data_date = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'),by = 'day', length.out = 100),
  Percent.Change = runif(5,1,100)
)

jobsAFAM2 <- data.frame(
  data_date = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'),by = 'day', length.out = 100),
  Percent.Change = runif(5,1,100)
)

jobsAFAM <- merge(jobsAFAM1, jobsAFAM2, by="data_date")

jobsAFAMMelted <- reshape2::melt(jobsAFAM, id.var='data_date')

ggplot(jobsAFAMMelted, aes(x=data_date, y=value, col=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: reshape2 is outdated, it is didactically better to use its successor dplyr right away

Comment: Hi @FranzPlumpton. Would you mind giving an example using dplyr?

Answer (score 3):

This is old, just update new tidyverse workflow not mentioned above.

```
library(tidyverse)

jobsAFAM1 <- tibble(
    date = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'),by = 'day', length.out = 5),
    Percent.Change = runif(5, 0,1)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(serial='jobsAFAM1')
jobsAFAM2 <- tibble(
    date = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2017-01-01'),by = 'day', length.out = 5),
    Percent.Change = runif(5, 0,1)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(serial='jobsAFAM2')
jobsAFAM <- bind_rows(jobsAFAM1, jobsAFAM2)

ggplot(jobsAFAM, aes(x=date, y=Percent.Change, col=serial)) + geom_line()
```

@Chris Njuguna

tidyr::gather() is the one in tidyverse workflow to turn wide dataframe to long tidy layout, then ggplot could plot multiple serials.

[image: gather]

Comment: @visitanz The progression to newer ways of doing it seems like a good reason to keep this question open. Would you create a toy example like in the previous answers/comments?

Comment: @Chris Njuguna, I've changed your example code in tidyverse workflow.

Comment: @visitanz Neat!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to bind the dataframes, and assign them the type of variable they represent. This will let you use the full dataset in a [tidier way](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(dates = 1:10,Variable = rnorm(mean = 0.5,10))
df2 <- data.frame(dates = 1:10,Variable = rnorm(mean = -0.5,10))

df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Type = 'a') %>%
  bind_rows(df2 %>%
              mutate(Type = 'b'))


ggplot(df3,aes(y = Variable,x = dates,color = Type)) + 
  geom_line()
```