# How to format the scatterplots of data series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have been struggling in creating a decent looking scatterplot in R. I wouldn't think it was so difficult.
After some research, it seemed to me that `ggplot` would have been a choice allowing plenty of formatting. However, I'm struggling in understanding how it works.
I'd like to create a scatterplot of two data series, displaying the points with two different colours, and perhaps different shapes, and a legend with series names.
Here is my attempt, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921842/plotting-multiple-time-series-on-the-same-plot-using-ggplot):

```
year1 <- mpg[which(mpg$year==1999),]
year2 <- mpg[which(mpg$year==2008),]

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = year1, aes(x=cty,y=hwy,color="yellow"))  +
  geom_point(data = year2, aes(x=cty,y=hwy,color="green")) +
  xlab('cty') +
  ylab('hwy')
```

Now, this looks almost OK, but with non-matching colors (unless I suddenly became color-blind). Why is that?
Also, how can I add series names and change symbol shapes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build 2 different dataframes:

```
df <- mpg[which(mpg$year%in%c(1999,2008)),]
df$year<-as.factor(df$year)
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x=cty,y=hwy,color=year,shape=year))  +
  xlab('cty') +
  ylab('hwy')+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green","yellow"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(2,8))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend("Year"),
         shape = guide_legend("Year"))
```

Comment: Brilliant, and how to control symbol shapes in this framework?

Comment: You can add `shape=as.factor(year)` in the `aes ()` and `+scale_shape_manual(values=c(...))` to set them to whatever fits your needs.

Comment: That works, thanks, but then I get two legends: one for the colours and one for the shapes... Can I 'merge' the legends in some way?

Comment: So, it looks that one needs to create two identical guide_legend() in order for R to understand that it's the same one, right?

Comment: No, you can skip the `guides()` part, because `color` and `shape` both refer to the same `label` (year) you will only have one legend. However, if you want a custom title (I put Year here) you need to specify `guide` and provide the same title for each `scale` so that it stays one. You can play around with it a bit and you will quickly understand how `ggplot`deals with it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with the way you currently have it set-up:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = year1, aes(x=cty,y=hwy), col = "yellow", shape=1)  +
  geom_point(data = year2, aes(x=cty,y=hwy), col="green", shape=2) +
  xlab('cty') +
  ylab('hwy')
```

Comment: I see. So 'col' and 'shape' are options of geom_point() and not of aes()...
And how to add a legend with customized series names? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy, color=as.factor(year)))+geom_point()
```